# For which values of $a$ the equation $4x-\left|3x-|x+a|\right|=9|x-1|$ has two answers?

Tags: inequality, roots, absolute-value

For which values of $a$ the equation $4x-\left|3x-|x+a|\right|=9|x-1|$ has two roots?

I wrote the equation as $$4x-9|x-1|=\left|3x-|x+a|\right|$$
We have $4x-9|x-1|\ge0$. Hence $\frac9{13}\le x\le \frac95$. So I found domain of $x$.

To continue, I tried squaring both side of the equation but it makes things more complicated.

Comment: Working through cases is an option.

Comment: 1) For various values of $a$, what does the LHS look like? Can you show that it is a non-decreasing graph? Can you show that the slope is never $> 8 $? 2) Hence, looking at the slope on the RHS, if there are exactly two roots, can you show that 1 root is $ < 1$ and the other root is $ > 1$?  3) Hence, what does this imply?

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks, from your hint I realized by the graph only one half line of the absolute value function of LHS intersect the graph of RHS from that we can argue that one root is less than $1$ and another more than $1$. But I till couldn't figure out how to use it to find $a$
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ f(x) = 4x - | 3x - |x+a| |$ and $ g(x) =  9 |x-1 | $.

**Hints:** (If you're stuck, show what you've tried.)

1. Show that $f(x)$ is non-decreasing.
2. Show that slope of $f(x)$ (except at kink points) is $ 4 \pm 3 \pm 1 = \{ 0, 2, 4, 8 \}$.
3. Show that slope of $ g(x) $ is either -9 or 9. What are the corresponding domains?
4. Show that on $ x \in ( -\infty , 1 ]$, there is at most 1 solution to $ f(x) = g(x)$. What is a (simple) necessary and sufficient condition (NASC) for there to be 1 solution?
5. Show that on $ x \in (1, \infty)$, there is at most 1 solution to $ f(x) = g(x)$.  Show that the NASC from before is still a necessary and sufficient condition for there to be 1 solution.
6. Hence, if there are 2 solutions to $f(x) = g(x)$, then NASC holds.
7. Hence, conclude what the values of $a$ are.

---

The NASC that I'm thinking of is

> $f(1) > g(1) = 0 $.
>  You still have to show that this is necessary and sufficient.